# Recover High Frequency Loss in a Simulated Power Spectrum

Tags: matlab, filters, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density

I'd like to ask a theoretical question about power spectra.
In MATLAB, by means of a particular approach, I'm trying to generate a Gaussian variable which embodies a particular power spectrum.
The theoretical power spectrum has been calculated over an illimited range (`[-Inf,Inf]`), whereas the simulated one is obtained only in a short wave number vector range.

Generally, theoretical power spectrum and simulated one look like in the figure below
[image]

`Red` and `green` plots represent the simulated spectrum for two different configuration; the `blue` line stays for the theoretical spectrum.

I'd like to know if there is any easy way to recover the spectrum loss in the high frequency region, in order to force the simulated spectrum perfectly match the theoretical. I was thinking of a fairly easy filter working this way

```
filter = sqrt(S_th.^2./S_sim.^2);

S_rec = filter.*S_sim;
```

Do you believe such a procedure is allowed and physically reasonable?

there

Comment: Gaussian random variables do not have power spectra; Gaussian processes (_sequences_ of Gaussian random variables) do. If your simulated Gaussian random process has power spectral density $S_{\scriptstyle{\text{sim}}}(f)$ and you want to convert the _process_ to one that has power spectral density $S_{\scriptstyle{\text{desired}}}(f)$, you have to pass the _process_ through a linear time-invariant filter whose transfer function is $$\sqrt{\frac{S_{\scriptstyle{\text{desired}}}(f)}{S_{\scriptstyle{\text{sim}}}(f)}}$$ not just multiply the power spectral density by `filter` the way you have it.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: you are right when talking of Gaussian processes compared to Gaussian variable. I'm sorry for the mistake. Do you believe what you proposed is feasable? Or does it have any negative impact to keep into account?